# Reference outside the sealed class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class, inner-classes, sealed, data-class

I'm trying to create a class that uses its own state to operate on the state of an external object that it holds a reference to.  The external object can be of class A or B, which are similar, but not controlled by the author.  So a sealed class is created to access their common attributes, per [this earlier answer from @SimY4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275163/polymorphism-on-extension-functions-in-kotlin).

```
// *** DOES NOT COMPILE ***
class A {   // foreign class whose structure is not modifiable
  val prop get()= "some string made the Class-A way"
}
class B {   // foreign class whose structure is not modifiable
  val prop get()= "some string made the Class-B way"
}
data class ABTool (val obj:AB, val i:Int, val j:Int) {
  // class that manipulates i and j and uses them to do
  // things with AB's "common" attributes through the sealed class AB
  sealed class AB {   // substitute for a common interface
    abstract val prop: String
    abstract val addmagic: String
    data class BoxA(val o:A) : AB() {
      override val prop get()= o.prop
      override val addmagic get() = prop + this@???.magic  // HOW TO REFERENCE?
    }
    data class BoxB(val o:B) : AB() {
      override val prop get()= o.prop
      override val addmagic get() = this@???.magic + prop  // HOW TO REFERENCE?
    }
  }
  val magic get()= "magic: ${i*j}"
}
```

The problem now is that I've figured out I can't operate on the external object in the way I want, because a sealed class can't refer to its outer class members.  Is there a better way to make this work, even if using a different approach (other than sealed class), while:

- not changing foreign classes A or B;
- respecting that A and B (and many others in the real case) are similar, so I'm trying to write one tool that calculates and adds magic to A and B with the same code base; and
- noting that although the ABTool tools are the same, the way they are applied to add magic is slightly different in A vs. B, just as the to access the conceptually common elements of A and B may be different.

Any thoughts on this or a similar workaround?  Maybe a more functional approach that I haven't conceived yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ABTool` being a sealed class is something you can give up, then here's a solution:

1. Replace `sealed` with `inner abstract` at the `ABTool` declaration;
2. Mark `BoxA` and `BoxB` as `inner` as well;

```
data class ABTool(val obj: AB, val i: Int, val j: Int) {
    inner abstract class AB {
        abstract val prop: String
        abstract val addmagic: String

        inner class BoxA(val o: A) : AB() {
            override val prop get() = o.prop
            override val addmagic get() = prop + magic
        }

        inner class BoxB(val o: B) : AB() {
            override val prop get() = o.prop
            override val addmagic get() = magic + prop
        }
    }

    val magic get() = "magic: ${i * j}"
}
```

(alternatively, instead of marking `AB` as inner, move `BoxA` and `BoxB` out of it to the scope of `ABTool`)

Comment: I'm confused as to how to instantiate.  Given `val a=A()`, I've tried `ABTool.AB.BoxA(a)` .  I think `BoxA` wants me to instantiate `AB`, maybe because `BoxA` is inner? `ABTool.AB().BoxA(a)` doesn't work, maybe because `AB` is abstract?  `ABTool().AB().BoxA(a)` doesn't work, maybe because ABTool needs constructors?... But constructing it is what I'm trying to do in the first place.  Am I missing that this needs to be in a companion class or something?  **Can you help me understand how to instantiate it?** Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it's complicated. Do you need `val obj: AB` in the primary constructor of `ABTool`? When it's there, you need to create an `AB` (`BoxA` or `BoxB`) before you create `ABTool`, but since they are `inner`, they require an `ABTool` instance to exist at that time.

Comment: Forgetting the outer data class for a moment, here's an even simpler part I can't grasp... If constructors of `BoxA` and `BoxB` (because they are `inner`) depend upon an *instance* of AB to be seen, and an object instance of `AB` type can only be created by making a `BoxA` or `BoxB` (since `AB` is abstract and `BoxA` and `BoxB` are the only classes that have `AB` as a superclass) ... can they ever be instantiated?  (I keep thinking I'm missing a critical link in my understanding of inner classes...)

Comment: Since inner class within abstract class might be something that could be a useful answer on its own, [I started a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384785/inner-class-within-its-abstract-superclass-in-kotlin).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to add an `ABTool` field to `AB`:

```
sealed class AB(val tool: ABTool) {
  abstract val prop: String
  abstract val addmagic: String
  data class BoxA(val o:A, tool: ABTool) : AB(tool) {
    override val prop get()= o.prop
    override val addmagic get() = prop + tool.magic
  }
  data class BoxB(val o:B, tool: ABTool) : AB(tool) {
    override val prop get()= o.prop
    override val addmagic get() = tool.magic + prop
  }
}
```

and pass `this` when creating it from `ABTool`. That's just what `inner` really does, after all.

In this specific case the field happens to be unused in `AB` itself and so you can remove it from there and make it `val` in `BoxA` and `BoxB`.