# Inner class within its abstract superclass in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class, instantiation, inner-classes

If a set of inner classes are the only implementations (subclasses) of their outer abstract containing class, how does one instantiate them?

```
abstract class A {
    inner class A1 : A()
    inner class A2 : A()
}
```

In other words, **what is the syntax to construct an instance of `A1` or `A2`?**

**EDIT:** ... outside the body of class A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
abstract class A {
    fun doSome() { // OK
        val a1 = A1()
        val a2 = A2()
    }
    inner class A1 : A()
    inner class A2 : A()
}
```

I think you probably want to construct instances of A1/A2 outside of A, like:

```
abstract class A {
    inner class A1 : A()
    inner class A2 : A()
}
fun doSome() { // Error
    val a1 = A1()
    val a2 = A2()
}
```

This is not allowed in both Kotlin and Java, because the inner class holds pointers to the outer class. If you want to construct `A1/A2` outside of `A`, simply remove the `inner` modifiers.

```
abstract class A {
    class A1 : A()
    class A2 : A()
}

fun doSome() { // OK
    val a1 = A.A1()
    val a2 = A.A2()
}
```

Also, in addition, since you said it's

> a set of inner classes are the only implementations (subclasses) of their outer abstract containing class

You can replace `abstract` modifier with `sealed`. This will help Kotlin do exhautiveness check in `when` expression.

Comment: You're right.  I should have said **outside of A**.  [Here's the particular use case I'm trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361279), which was a sealed class originally.  A is really a quasi-interface, and A1 and A2 are boxed foreign classes I don't control.  Could you give a read and maybe answer there too if you have ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Please mention that you just need to construct the inner class with an instance of the outer class. Maybe you should write a function in the outer class that returns the instance of the inner class.